# Res.send not a function

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

I have an endpoint (using express) which requires me to do some fetching first. Once a parse the response and use res.send I get an error `res.send is not a function`.

I tried searching for this error but all searches show users had `res,req` in the wrong order. In this case, mine appear to be right.

Why is it res is not scope after a convert my response to JSON?

```
router.post("/customerID", async (req, res) => {
  return fetch({endPoint}, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Flowspace-Auth": {myToken},
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `query {
        user {
          name
          organizationId
        }
      }`,
    }),
  })
    .then((res) => {
        res.json().then((data) => {
        console.log(data) // This works
        res.send({ data: data }); // res.send is not a function... why, is it not scoped correctly?
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("unable to fetch:", err));
});
```

Comment: Hi @Bromax,
Is this related to https://flow.space/ API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer `response` variable is overwritten by your inner `result` variable. JS goes from the inner most scope to outer most looking for variable. Since, `res` is already defined in the `then` clause, that `res` is used.

Changing it to `resp` should work.

```
router.post("/customerID", async (req, resp) => {
  return fetch({endPoint}, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Flowspace-Auth": {myToken},
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `query {
        user {
          name
          organizationId
        }
      }`,
    }),
  })
    .then((res) => {
        res.json().then((data) => {
        console.log(data) // This works
        resp.send({ data: data }); // resp will belong to outer response
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("unable to fetch:", err));
});
```

You probably want to send something in the `catch` part too.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling send method on the response of the fetch api call on which the send method is not available. find the correct code below.

```
    router.post("/customerID", async (req, res) => {
    return fetch(
    { endPoint },
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Flowspace-Auth": { myToken },
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        query: `query {
        user {
            name
            organizationId
        }
        }`,
        }),
    }
    )
    .then((response) => {
        response.json().then((data) => {
        console.log(data); // This works
        res.send({ data: data }); 
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("unable to fetch:", err));
});
```